# Small utility library is acting in a bizarre fashion?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to add a small utility fucntion to my library when I noticed that my utility library was returning an application object.

It is returning an object from a completely other file.  My application is completely private and in an IIFE.

You can view the application here

```
www.arcmarks.com
```

in the console type in

```
localStorage.file_arcmarks_js
```

to see the application file which is stored in localStorage.

`var CArcmarks` holds the object that has seemingly gone global on its own and is now being returned by utility functions.

in the console type in

```
$A.extend({});
```

too see that it returns

```
Object { Name:CArcmarks ...
```

which is an object in the application file.

Extend is a basic utility function that copies one object from another and if you view the source

```
$A.extend
```

you can see it is a pretty simple function.

How does it return this.  It is bizarre.

This is in Chrome by the way.  I'm checking other browsers... not in FF.  Perhaps some bizarre Chrome bug?

I feel like I'm in the twilight zone, does anyone else see this or did someone drug my Mocha.

Per comments here is the code for CArcmarks, and $A.extend().

```
// *Pub is released to $A.
// does not extend through the prototype chain like similar underscore version
Pub.extend = function (obj) {

    // loop through elements beyond obj
    Pub.someIndex(nativeSlice.call(arguments, 1), function (val) {

        // extend it
        Pub.someKey(val, function (val_inner, key) {
            obj[key] = val_inner;
        });
    });
    return obj;
};
```

In a separate file:

```
/***************************************************************************************************
**CArcmarks
*/

    var CArcmarks = $A.Class.create({
        Name: 'CArcmarks',
        A: {
            toggle_page_lazy:           'toggle_page_lazy',
            toggle_page_active:         'toggle_page_active',
            toggle_tag_active:          'toggle_tag_active',
            toggle_tag_lazy:            'toggle_tag_lazy'
        },
        render: function (obj, el) {

            // element to render into is passed and a ns is extracted from the id
            // from this additional elements are extracted
            this.el = el;
            this.ns = el.id + '_';
            this.el_arcmarks = $A.el('#' + el.id + '_arcmarks');
            this.el_tags = $A.el('#' + el.id + '_tags');

            // holds data from the server to be inserted into template
            this.obj = obj;
            this.tags = {};
            this.composePane();
        },
        composePane: function () {

            // abstract out a page_string so the HTML is not tangled in the JavaScript
            var //favorite_string = '',
                tag_string = '',
                page_string = '',
                current_id,
                previous_id;
            _.each(this.obj, function (val) {
                previous_id = current_id;
                current_id = this.ns + val.tag;

                // a new tag has been found, create page and tag
                if ((previous_id !== current_id) || (previous_id === undefined)) {
                    this.tags[current_id] = '';
                    tag_string += this.composeTag(current_id);
                    page_string += this.composePage(current_id);

                    /*
                    if (previous_id !== undefined) {
                        favorite_string += '</div>';
                    }
                    favorite_string += this.composePage(current_id);
                    */
                }
                this.tags[current_id] += this.composeFavorite(val);
                // favorite_string += this.composeFavorite(val);
            }, this);

            // favorite_string = favorite_string + '</div>';
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.tags)) {
                this.el_arcmarks.innerHTML = page_string;
                // this.el_arcmarks.innerHTML = favorite_string;
                this.el_tags.innerHTML = tag_string;
                this.insertFavorites();
                this.initPane();
            }
        },
        insertFavorites: function () {
            $A.someChild(this.el_arcmarks, function (val) {
                if (val.id) {
                    val.innerHTML = this.tags[val.id.slice(0,-5)];
                }
            }, this);
        },
        composePage: function (current_id) {
            return _.template($('#item-page').html(), {
                foo: current_id + '_page'
            });
        },
        composeFavorite: function (val) {
            return _.template($('#item-arcmark').html(), {
                id:    this.ns + val.id,
                ida:   this.ns + val.id + 'a',
                idb:   this.ns + val.id + 'b',
                src:   val.favicon !== null ? val.favicon : 'http://arcmarks.com/arcmarks/images/image_null_50.png',
                href:  val.url,
                title: val.title
            });
        },
        composeTag: function (current_id) {
            var self = this;
            return _.template($('#item-tag').html(), {
                id:   current_id,
                foo:  current_id.slice(self.ns.length)
            });
        },
        initPane: function () {
            var self = this;
            _.each(this.tags, function (val, key) {
                $A.el('#' + key).addEventListener("click", function () {
                    self.flip(this);
                });
            }, this);
            this.flip($A.el('#' + $A.firstKey(this.tags)));
        },
        flip: function (tag_element) {
            var page_element = $A.el('#' + tag_element.id + '_page');

            // turn current page/tag on
            $A.toggleClass(page_element, this.A.toggle_page_active);
            $A.toggleClass(tag_element, this.A.toggle_tag_active);

            // turn off previous page/tag if it exists and it is not also the current
            if (this.prev_page_el && (tag_element.id !== this.prev_tag_el.id)) {
                $A.toggleClass(this.prev_page_el, this.A.toggle_page_lazy);
                $A.toggleClass(this.prev_tag_el, this.A.toggle_tag_lazy);
            }
            this.prev_page_el = page_element;
            this.prev_tag_el = tag_element;
        },
        insertFavorite: function (obj_fav) {
            var tag_id = this.ns + obj_fav.tag,
                div_el,
                html_string = this.composeFavorite(obj_fav),
                page_el = $A.el('#' + tag_id + '_page');
            div_el = $A.HTMLToElement(html_string);
            if (!page_el) {
                page_el = this.insertTagAndPage(tag_id);
            }
            $A.someChild(page_el, function (iter) {
                if (iter === null) {
                    page_el.appendChild(div_el);
                    return true;
                }
                if (obj_fav.title < iter.children[1].innerHTML) {
                    page_el.insertBefore(div_el, iter);
                    return true;
                }
                if (iter === page_el.lastChild) {
                    page_el.appendChild(div_el);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            this.flip($A.el('#' + tag_id));
            return div_el;
        },
        insertTagAndPage: function (tag) {
            var par_el,
                div_el,
                hold_tags_el,
                hold_arcmarks_el,
                self = this;
            hold_tags_el = this.el_tags;
            hold_arcmarks_el = this.el_arcmarks;
            par_el = $A.createElement('p');

            // update this
            par_el.innerHTML = tag.slice(this.ns.length);
            par_el.className = "single_tag";
            par_el.id = tag;

            // insert the tag(<p>)
            $A.someChild(hold_tags_el, function (iter) {
                if (iter === null) {
                    hold_tags_el.appendChild(par_el);
                    return true;
                }
                if (par_el.id < iter.id) {
                    hold_tags_el.insertBefore(par_el, iter);
                    return true;
                }
                if (iter === hold_tags_el.lastChild) {
                    hold_tags_el.appendChild(par_el);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            par_el.addEventListener("click", function () {
                self.flip(this);
            });
            div_el = $A.createElement('div');
            div_el.className = "bookmark_page";
            div_el.id = tag + "_page";
            div_el.style.display = "";
            $A.someChild(hold_arcmarks_el, function (iter) {
                if (iter === null) {
                    hold_arcmarks_el.appendChild(div_el);
                    return true;
                }
                if (div_el.id < iter.id) {
                    hold_arcmarks_el.insertBefore(div_el, iter);
                    return true;
                }
                if (iter === hold_arcmarks_el.lastChild) {
                    hold_arcmarks_el.appendChild(div_el);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return div_el;
        }
    }, 'constructor');
```

Comment: Can't you post the relevant code here?

Comment: Posted code for CArcmarks.

Comment: more interesting would be the `extend` method.

Comment: It's a bug with the chrome dev tools; it seems that it mixed up some variables. The memory contents are fine, though; if you do `JSON.stringify($A.extend({}))` you'll get `"{}"` back.

Comment: Could you please post the whole "small utility library"?

Comment: @univerio no, it's not. try `console.log({});` it will give the same result, meaning that at some point he is probably extending the native `Object` object.

Comment: So I looked a bit further through the code, but I couldn't find the exact spot where things go wrong. But one thing seems to be clear. It has nothing to do with the `extend` function. As pointed out in my last comment, every newly created object already has those extra properties inherited from their prototype. This means that somewhere in your code or in the code of the library, the prototype of the `Object` object gets extended like `Object.prototype.xy = 1; ({}).xy === 1; //true` (but probably in a more indirect way).

Comment: @basilikum You're right, `Object.prototype` gives some garbage object.

Comment: I never extend the prototype chain for Object, this is known as an anti-pattern or bad practice according to addy osmani

Comment: You can view the whole library here - http://arcmarks.com/arcmarks/source/arc.js

Comment: I'm going to delete this and re-post it in a bit as the question is not formed well, it has nothing to do with any particular function as of yet.

Comment: @user3293653 I'm not saying that you did it on purpose. There is probably some bug in your code, that results in the prototype being extended like that. Fact is, that it IS extended (or replaced). So you should track it down, for instance by checking the prototype on several locations in your code to narrow down where it swaps from not extended to extended.

Comment: well, yea it's a bug, but so weird in the fact that I don't normally mess with the prototype chain in general, yet alone with Object.prototype, in fact a search for Object.prototype in my code base only pulls up one use and that is to set use Object.prototype.slice.